# Distribution inside css columns

Tags: html, css

I have been researching and experimenting with HTML5 and CSS3, aiming to create a very simple but efficient tiled gallery/grids system.

Below is what I have created. The problem is, the image/div distribution changes from browser to another, why is it doing that? can we control it?

I tried adding `"column-fill: auto"` but it didn't work. What I am doing wrong?

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6C2Jb/).

HTML:

```
<div class="grids">
    <div class="gridElement">
        <img alt="image" src="assets/images/image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="gridElement">
        <img alt="image" src="assets/images/image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="gridElement">
        <img alt="image" src="assets/images/image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="gridElement">
        <img alt="image" src="assets/images/image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="gridElement">
        <img alt="image" src="assets/images/image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="gridElement">
        <img alt="image" src="assets/images/image.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

CSS:
/*Grids System*/
 .grids {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
.grids.twoGrids {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
.grids.fourGrids {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
}
.grids .gridElement {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.grids .gridElement:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.grids .gridElement img {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: "The problem is, the image/div distribution changes from browser to another" : explain/show example screenshot or something. 
Works fine for me in FF and Chrome.

Comment: IS there anything really called: column-fill: balance ?

Comment: Hi are you looking for this:- http://jsfiddle.net/6C2Jb/3/

Answer (score 0):

[W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#column-fill)

Syntax

```
column-fill: auto or balance;
```

Values

```
auto : Fills columns sequentially.

balance (by default) : content equally between columns, if possible.
```

CSS

```
column-fill: balance; /* W3C */
-webkit-column-fill: balance; /* Safari & Chrome */
-moz-column-fill: balance; /* Firefox */
-ms-column-fill: balance; /* Internet Explorer */
-o-column-fill: balance; /* Opera */
```

Comment: But is this really supported anywhere?